# Difference between anyMatch and findAny in java 8

Tags: java, arrays, java-8, java-stream

I have an `Array` and want to perform some matching on it's element.

I came to know that it could be done in two ways in `java 8` :

```java
String[] alphabet = new String[]{"A", "B", "C"};
```

**anyMatch :**

```java
Arrays.stream(alphabet).anyMatch("A"::equalsIgnoreCase);
```

**findAny :**

```java
Arrays.stream(alphabet).filter("a"::equalsIgnoreCase)
        .findAny().orElse("No match found"));
```

As I can understand both are doing the same work. However, I could not found which one to prefer?

Could someone please make it clear what is the difference between both of them.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

They do the same job internally, but their return value is different. [`Stream#anyMatch()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) returns a `boolean` while [`Stream#findAny()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findAny--) returns an object which matches the predicate.

Comment: They _almost_ do the same work. `anyMatch` is a short-circuit operation, but `filter` will always process the whole stream.

Comment: @JornVernee are you entirely certain of that statement? As far as I remember streams are "lazy", which, for sequential streams, means that after encountering the first matching value in anyMatch it will be returned and the filter will not be processed further.

Comment: Hmm, I suppose you are right. At least it depends on the implementation. I'm going of the documentation here, where only `anyMatch` explicitly mentions that it's a short-circuit operation.

Comment: @JornVernee findAny code : `if (!stop && predicate.test(t) == matchKind.stopOnPredicateMatches) { stop = true; ...` it is short-circuiting.

Comment: @Eugene is that the JDK9 implementation? The `findAny` I have doesn't accept a predicate

Comment: @JornVernee that's the third time this week! :( yes, it is jdk-9; that's the default I have. sorry

Comment: @MehrajMalik Well, it's supposed to come out on [2017/07/27](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk9/) That's not too long from now.

Comment: @JornVernee I checked, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44180155/is-stream-findany-a-short-circuit-operation

Comment: @JornVernee you might have some "substance" here. One is implemented via `FindOps` and the other via `MatchOps`. It could have been easily done so that `match` would call `find` and just return `isPresent` on the resulting `Optional`. I just know I will not be able to sleep normally until I understand why...

Comment: Another example how Java lambdas are very inconsistent and confusing in their syntax. Instead of `anyMatch` they should have added `exists()` without predicate. So streams become reusable and always follow same pattern. Would be so easy intuitive with `stream.filter().exists()` instead. All part till filter is reusable for example in a DAO first check with same stream exists any and then load a paginated resultset.

Answer (score 4):

#### There are more than two ways in `Java 8`

```java
String[] alphabet = new String[]{"A", "B", "C"};
```

The difference is in the type of the return value:

1. [`Stream#findAny()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findAny--):

   > Returns an [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) describing some element of the stream, or an empty Optional if the stream is empty.

   ```java
   String result1 = Arrays.stream(alphabet)
           .filter("a"::equalsIgnoreCase)
           .findAny()
           .orElse("none match");
   ```
2. [`Stream#findFirst()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst--)

   > Returns an [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) describing the first element of this stream, or an empty Optional if the stream is empty. If the stream has no encounter order, then any element may be returned.

   ```java
   String result2 = Arrays.stream(alphabet)
           .filter("a"::equalsIgnoreCase)
           .findFirst()
           .orElse("none match");
   ```
3. [`Stream#count()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#count--)

   > Returns the count of elements in this stream. This is a special case of a [`reduction`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Reduction) and is equivalent to:
   >
   > ```
   > return mapToLong(e -> 1L).sum();
   > ```

   ```java
   boolean result3 = Arrays.stream(alphabet)
           .filter("a"::equalsIgnoreCase)
           .count() > 0;
   ```
4. [`Stream#anyMatch(Predicate)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-)

   > Returns whether any elements of this stream match the provided [`Predicate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html). May not evaluate the predicate on all elements if not necessary for determining the result. If the stream is empty then false is returned and the predicate is not evaluated.

   ```java
   boolean result4 = Arrays.stream(alphabet)
           .anyMatch("a"::equalsIgnoreCase);
   ```
5. [`Stream#allMatch(Predicate)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#allMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-)

   > Returns whether all elements of this stream match the provided [`Predicate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html). May not evaluate the predicate on all elements if not necessary for determining the result. If the stream is empty then true is returned and the predicate is not evaluated.

   ```java
   boolean result5 = Arrays.stream(alphabet)
           .allMatch("a"::equalsIgnoreCase);
   ```