# Best performance to search a number in a column of a 2d array without cloning the array

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, search, multidimensional-array

I am trying to search for a number in a particular column of a two dimensional array. I tried a few different approach and would like to use stream in Java 8. However, it doesn't seem to be the best performance. Wonder if someone can help?

```
boolean isInColumn(int col, int number) {
    return IntStream.range(0, board.length)
        .map(i -> board[i][col])
        .filter(num -> num == number )
        .findFirst()
        .isPresent();
}
```

trying to search in a block as well. Any hints?

```
public boolean isInBlock(int row, int col, int number) {
    int r = row - row % 3;
    int c = col - col % 3;

    for (int i = r; i < r + 3; i++) {
        for (int j = c; j < c + 3; j++) {
            if (board[i][j] == number)
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

the input data is the following array.

```
public static int[][] PUZZLE = {
    {9,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,5},
    {0,0,5,0,9,0,2,0,1},
    {8,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,8,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,7,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,2,6,0,0,9},
    {2,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,6},
    {0,0,0,2,0,0,9,0,0},
    {0,0,1,9,0,4,5,7,0},
};
```

Comment: What seems to be your performance issue? I checked the stream version compared to a naive way and the difference is only milliseconds which most likely due to measuring it the wrong way. However, the naive way was always faster though.

`static boolean isInColumn2(int col, int number) {
        for (int[] ints : PUZZLE) {
            if (ints[col] == number)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
`

Comment: @SzaPe What if the amount of data will be much larger, and you will need to process it in real-time? Even a difference of milliseconds can be crucial (of course if they are not the result of an error in the measurement of time).

Comment: In case the data could be much larger, you should have mentioned that in the first place. 
I tested it with a 30000x30000 array, running both methods 1000 times. The naive way comes out around 3-4 times faster

Comment: If you are doing really large arrays, then maybe using `parallelStream()` could be interesting. But rest assured: for anything below the "many thousands rows/columns" order of magnitude, the plain old school naive code will beat stream-ish solutions. You have to understand that "streams" means establishing a complex hierarchy of objects. They give you easy to read and maintain code, that *can* give you good performance if you know what you are doing. But they aren't a silver bullet *designed* for mac performance!

Answer (score 1):

This 'stream'-version seems a little bit optimzed, but I think searching for a hit in an array will always be faster the old fashioned way, see [Java performance tutorial – How fast are the Java 8 streams?](https://jaxenter.com/java-performance-tutorial-how-fast-are-the-java-8-streams-118830.html)

```
boolean isInColumn(int col, int number) {
    return IntStream.range(0, board.length)
        .anyMatch(i -> (board[i][col] == number) );
}
```

I made a short attempt with a parallel stream, but the overhead made it far worse.
I think it would be different if the action wasn't a simple compare...

If it's only about speed for a Sudoku-solver/generator maybe you shouldn't loop at all but write the 9 conditions in one return statement

```
return board[0,col] == number || board[1,col] == number ...
```

Comment: Well, unless you can get to parallel streams, then you might get to faster results on really large data and systems with many CPUs at hand. But only then

Comment: @GhostCat : I agree, I used always carelessly, but the comment about big data wasn't from the author himself, the question is about a 9x9 array.

Comment: Sure, but asks about performance at the same time. I wouldnt be surprised if the 9x9 naive solution is orders of magnitudes faster than a stream solution here.

Comment: @GhostCat : Right again, but assuming it's abaot a Sudoku-solver(or generator, I think RoToRA is right) there will be lots of calls of  isInColumn and isInBlock.

Comment: Which makes things ... worse?

Comment: Kindof, so I added  "don't loop at all for Sudoku" to my answer

Answer (score 0):

Since this seems to be Sudoku what you could do is store the data redundantly. Don't only store the numbers in "normally" in a two dimensional array, but also have two-dimensional boolean arrays, where you store whether the row/column/block contains the number.

```
class Sudoku {

  private final int[][] puzzle = new int[9][9];
  
  private final boolean[][] rows = new boolean[9][9];
  private final boolean[][] columns = new boolean[9][9];
  private final boolean[][] blocks = new boolean[9][9];

  public void setCell(int row, in column, int number) {
    puzzle[row][column] = number;
    
    rows[row][number - 1] = true;
    columns[column][number - 1] = true;
    blocks[calcBlockId(row, column)][number - 1] = true;
 }

  // returns a number (0 - 8) identifying a block 
  // 0 - 2 is first line, 3 - 5 second line, etc.
  private int calcBlockId(int row, int column) {
    // Left as an exercise to the reader
  }
 
  public boolean isInColumn(int col, int number) {
     return columns[col][number - 1];
  }
 
  public boolean isInBlock(int row, int column, int number) {
    return blocks[calcBlockId(row, column)][number - 1];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code searches for an element in a 2d array and returns the coordinates of the first match, if such an element is present, or null otherwise:

```java
public static int[] findElement(int[][] arr, int element) {
    return IntStream
            // iterate through the indexes
            // of the rows of the array
            .range(0, arr.length)
            // for each row
            .mapToObj(i -> {
                // look for the element in this row
                int j = IntStream
                        // iterate through the indexes
                        // of the elements of the row
                        .range(0, arr[i].length)
                        // filter a matching element
                        .filter(el -> arr[i][el] == element)
                        // take first match
                        .findFirst().orElse(-1);
                // if element is present
                if (j >= 0)
                    // return its coordinates
                    return new int[]{i, j};
                else
                    // or null otherwise
                    return null;
            })
            // take first non-null coordinates, if they are present
            .filter(Objects::nonNull).findFirst()
            // or null otherwise
            .orElse(null);
}
```

```java
// test
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] puzzle = {
            {9, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5},
            {0, 0, 5, 0, 9, 0, 2, 0, 1},
            {8, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 6, 0, 0, 9},
            {2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6},
            {0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 1, 9, 0, 4, 5, 7, 0}};

    int[] coordinates = findElement(puzzle, 7);

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(coordinates)); // [4, 3]
}
```

---

<sup>See also:

• [Difference between anyMatch and findAny in java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65890667/14940971)

• [First unique character in a string using LinkedHashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66387637/14940971)</sup>